# MySQL Results in Body of PHPMailer Email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to echo the results of a MySQL query into the body of an email to send via PHPMailer, but am having difficulties.  The query works as I successfully create the table on the page, but can't seem to get the assigning the table to a variable correct.

My Code:

```
$body = '<html>
                    <body>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Food</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Category</th>
                                <tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>'.
                            while($row = $resultOrderE->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                echo '
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>$row['food']</td>
                                            <td>$row['quantity']</td>
                                            <td>$row['category']</td>
                                        </tr>
                                ';}.'
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>';
```

The error I get is:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant concate a WHILE loop to a string.

you have to loop through and ADD to the existing string per iteration of the loop

```
$html_string = '<html><body><table><thead><tr><th>Food</th><th>Quantity</th> <th>Category</th><tr></thead><tbody>';

while($row = $resultOrderE->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $html_string .= 
  '<tr><td>'.$row['food'].'</td><td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td><td>'.$row['category'].'</td></tr>';
}

// this will add the closing tags and now html_string has your built email
$html_string .= '</tbody></table></body></html>';
```

so the `.=` is the important part, it concates a string to the end of existing string

Comment: Thanks very much.  Didn't know that, but it makes sense.